# How to get a list of all the training data from a keras DirectoryIterator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have used a DirectoryIterator to read a training set consisting of images, using the flow_from_directory method. Now I would like to plot an ROC plot of the result (eventually on a test set, obviously, but for the moment I'd also like to see ROC plot on the training set).

Being a total newbie on both Python, Keras and Tensorflow, I googled on how to plot ROC, and found this recipe:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#plot_the_roc

However, to use this approach, I need to get a list of labels (ground truths), and predictions. I can get predictions using model.predict, but for that I obviously need the input data (i.e. the images in the training set). What's the best way to obtain these images from the DirectoryIterator?

I suppose I could just make some kind of loop, getting one batch at a time from the DirectoryIterator. However, I noted that the DirectoryIterator contains a field [labels](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/DirectoryIterator#labels), which gives a list of labels (ground truths), one for each training example. So I figured there should be some equally simple way to get all the training inputs (since otherwise, what would be the point of getting just the labels?). But I can't find any field for this. So where can I find a list containing all the training inputs of the DirectoryIterator (sorted in the same order as the labels field, obviously)?

Answer (score -2):

A DirectoryIterator yields tuples of (x, y) where x is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, *target_size, channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels.
https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method

To access the (images, labels) you can do this using some for loop over that iterator.

```
 for each in DirectoryIterator:
     print(each[0].shape)
     print(each[1].shape)
     break
```

where each[0] gives you the images batch and each[1] the corresponding labels.